# Perl:Regex substitution

Tags: regex, perl

I want to write a regex to substitute remove white spaces within my string as follows:

String : `user1: group user2 :group2 user3 : group3` 
to

```
user1:group user2:group2 user3:group3
```

What I tried so far is:

```
$argument =~ s/\s+\:/\:/g;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are nearly there:

```
$argument =~ s/\s*:\s*/:/g;
```

There is no need to escape the `:`, and you want to search for whitespace both before and after the colon.  Instead of `\s+` which searches for one or more, I used `\s*` which searches for zero or more.  That way you will match if there are no spaces before but some after, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Edit (didn't notice that there could be spaces before the colon, too):

```
$yourString =~ s/\s*:\s*/:/g;
```

I think. Note that I do not in any way speak perl.